# How do I use database defaults for input fields?

Tags: c#, postgresql, sql-insert, default-value

I want to use database defaults for input boxes in c#
I have 3 columns. `orderID` (serial int) `order_time` (now()) and text column.

How do I make c# just input to text column so my database adds the int and timestamp itself?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter how is it unrelated, if OP asks for C# code snippet for that?

Comment: @YegorAndrosov: Does he? Well, I guess you could read it that way, too. Either way, it burns down to an SQL command.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter *it burns down to an SQL command*, it is not, if OP uses any ORM (Entity Framework for example). Then it can be achieved without **explicit** SQL commands. I am voting to close this question due to missing debugging details

Comment: An ORM is just a poor man's SQL generator. Still burns down to an SQL command.

Answer (score 2):

The `INSERT` statement can simply omit all columns that are supposed to get default values:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (text_column) VALUES ('user_input');
```

This results in `serial` being assigned the next number from the attached `SEQUENCE` and `time` being assigned the transaction timestamp `now()`.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

> Each column not present in the explicit or implicit column list will be filled with a default value, either its declared default value or null if there is none.

To be more explicit, you can alternatively use the `DEFAULT` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO tbl ("orderID", order_time, text_column)
VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 'user_input');
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

> `DEFAULT`
>
> The corresponding column will be filled with its default value. An
> identity column will be filled with a new value generated by the
> associated sequence. For a generated column, specifying this is
> permitted but merely specifies the normal behavior of computing the
> column from its generation expression.

You can even combine both: omit some columns and use `DEFAULT` for some others.